# Getting dismissed notification id

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, android-database

My app creates a notification and an item in a Data Base with that id.
When the user dismiss the notification I want to get that notification id, and using it to perform a research in the Data Base. I already have a pending Intent that allows me to know when a notification is dismissed.
The broadcast Reciever:

```
 final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           //Action to perform when notification is dismissed

            unregisterReceiver(this);
        }
    };
```

Code that creates a notification:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("NOTIFICATION_DELETED");
            PendingIntent pendintIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("NOTIFICATION_DELETED"));


            notification = new Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDeleteIntent(pendintIntent)
                    .build();

    notificationManager.notify(idUnico =(int)((new

        Date().

        getTime() /1000L)%Integer.MAX_VALUE),notification );

    reminder.setText("");
    titoloE.setText("");

        saveNotif();

        checkForConsent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the notificationId you are using to show notfication in the intent passed to pending intent.

```
int notifiId = (int)((new Date().getTime() /1000L)%Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Intent intent = new Intent("NOTIFICATION_DELETED");
// set id to intent
intent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", notifiId);

PendingIntent pendintIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("NOTIFICATION_DELETED"));

notification = new Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDeleteIntent(pendintIntent)
                .build();

notificationManager.notify(notifiId, notification);
```

Then in your broadcast receiver you can get the Id

```
 final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       //Action to perform when notification is dismissed
       if (intent.hasExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID") {
           int id = intent.getIntExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", -1);
           // Use Id
       }

        unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: It is strange because the app says that if (intent.hasExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID")) is false and does not execute it. I tried to delete the if statement and it gives the default value to "id".

id = intent.getIntExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID",0);

I used getIntExtra because there isn't "getInt"

Comment: SOLVED: PendingIntent pendintIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("NOTIFICATION_DELETED"));

Comment: @Jox Yeah, the methods are `getIntExtra()` and `putExtra()`. Glad you fixed your problem.